# X exists eternally. Which of the following ways to express this idea is better?

Tags: phrase-request

1. X never appeared.
2. X has never appeared.
3. X never came into being.
4. X has never come into being.

Comment: They're all fine. It really is just a stylistic choice how you want to express this concept, but for what it's worth I would *probably* go for #3 myself in most contexts.

Comment: I think that all of them are ambiguous, because they don't express the important fact that X never "appeared" because it has always existed.  It would be equally true to say "X never came into being (because it has always existed), and Y never came into being (because it has never existed)."  To be clear and unambiguous, it might be necessary to say something like "X never 'came into being' *per se*, having always existed."

Comment: Can it be "X always existed without ever coming  into being"?

Comment: That's not bad, although I think I would phrase it has "X has always existed, without ever having come into being."  I'm using *has always existed*, because it currently exists ("always existed" makes it sound like it was only in the past) and *without having come into being* because "without ever coming into being" sounds like a description of the present.

Comment: Will you make this an answer?